# Copying parent nodes

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to write a copy-constructor that is only allowed to copy from a parent node. Since I'm constrained to using `C++17`, I would like to accomplish this by imitating concepts/require clauses with the use of the `std::enable_if` type trait (if there is a better way to accomplish this, please let me know).

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<int N>
struct node {
    node() {
        std::cout << "def-ctor  N=" << N << "\n";
    }

    node(node const&) {
        std::cout << "cpy-ctor  N=" << N << "\n";
    }

    template<int O
        // , typename = std::enable_if_t<(N > O)>
    >
    node(node<O> const&) {
        std::cout << "cpy-ctor  N=" << N << " O=" << O << "  ";
        // static_assert(N > O);             // fails due to 3 > 4
        if constexpr (N > O)  std::cout << "N > O\n";
        if constexpr (N == O) std::cout << "N == O\n";
        if constexpr (N < O)  std::cout << "N < O\n";
    }
};

node<3> n3;
auto n4 = node<4>{n3};

//

template<int N>
using f = std::function<void(node<N> const&)>;

auto f3 = f<3>{[](auto const&){}};
auto f4 = f<4>{f3};

//

auto main() -> int {}
```

The code above prints the expected output:

`cpy-ctor  N=4 O=3  N > O`

But (to my surprise) when uncommenting the static-assert, the compilation fails stating that 3 sure can't be greater than 4. Which I can't really argue with, I guess.

I'm suspecting that some sort of copy-elision shenanigans is taking place here. Why under the hood a copy of the reversal is required, is beyond me.

So my question is: What is going on here? Why can't I constrain this copy-constructor to only accepts parent nodes? And how do I remedy this?

[Live example.](https://godbolt.org/z/4Tc33Gdbq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code and SFINAE usage for `node(node<O> const&)` (currently commented) look OK to me.

If I uncomment the `static_assert`, my local g++ 11.2.0 by msys2 yields the following error:

```
a.cpp: In instantiation of 'node<N>::node(const node<O>&) [with int O = 4; int N = 3]':
C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/invoke.h:61:36:   required from 'constexpr _Res std::__invoke_impl(std::__invoke_other, _Fn&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Res = void; _Fn = std::function<void(const node<3>&)>&; _Args = {const node<4>&}]'
C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/invoke.h:111:28:   required from 'constexpr std::enable_if_t<is_invocable_r_v<_Res, _Callable, _Args ...>, _Res> std::__invoke_r(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Res = void; _Callable = std::function<void(const node<3>&)>&; _Args = {const node<4>&}; std::enable_if_t<is_invocable_r_v<_Res, _Callable, _Args ...>, _Res> = void]'
C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/std_function.h:291:30:   required from 'static _Res std::_Function_handler<_Res(_ArgTypes ...), _Functor>::_M_invoke(const std::_Any_data&, _ArgTypes&& ...) [with _Res = void; _Functor = std::function<void(const node<3>&)>; _ArgTypes = {const node<4>&}]'
C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/std_function.h:422:21:   required from 'std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor) [with _Functor = std::function<void(const node<3>&)>; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; <template-parameter-2-3> = void; _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {const node<4>&}]'
a.cpp:35:18:   required from here
a.cpp:19:25: error: static assertion failed
   19 |         static_assert(N > O);             // fails due to 3 > 4
      |                       ~~^~~
a.cpp:19:25: note: '(3 > 4)' evaluates to false
```

Let's unpack.

1. It clearly wants to construct a `node<3>` from an existing `node<4>` *somewhere*.
2. This *somewhere* is required by the line `auto f4 = f<4>{f3};`
3. This line constructs a `std::function<void(node<4> const&)>` from an existing `std::function<void(node<3> const&)>`
4. The error happens in a helper function called `__invoke_impl`

How does one convert a function taking `node<3>` to a function taking `node<4>`? The only reasonable way is:

```cpp
void f4(node<4> const &arg) {
    return f3(arg);  // f3(node<3> const &)
}
```

Actually, that's more or less what `__invoke_impl` does.

Note that implicit conversion from `node<4>` to `node<3>` is required here. Hence, the program has to construct a `node<3>` object from a `node<4>` object. But `static_assert` prohibits that.

You can double-check this by replacing `static_assert` with either debug output or debugger breakpoint and seeing when it's actually called.

Comment: Great analysis! There are two remaining questions: Why is `cpy-ctor  N=3 O=4  N < O` never printed? This observation (or lack thereof) contradicts the static assert. What if I really want to make sure that copying only occurs from parent nodes? The inner logic of the copy constructor depends on that premise, which I can't enforce currently.

Comment: It is never printed because you never actually call `f4`. If I add `f4(n4)` in `main()`, it's printed. Both `static_assert` and SFINAE are good for enforcing contracts. The former causes hard compilation error, the latter causes "no overload"-like stuff which may be more useful for metaprogramming.

Comment: Ah, I see now. The encapsulated function code of the `std::function` object can never be dissipated. I'm not sure what I was expecting.... the static assert contradicting the `if constexpr` condition immediately below it remains an odd one. I still don't fully understand the mechanics of that. I'm leaving this question open for now in case someone would like to shed some light on that too.

Comment: `static_assert` fully happens during compilation. `if constexpr` guards a statement executed at runtime. If the method is not called, nothing is printed.

Comment: Ah, of course! Multiple instantiations are being stamped out of the templated copy-constructor. Each only containing the print statement that applies to them specifically. But the static assert is being *inserted* into each of them, which obviously can't hold true for both instantiations! This scenario could make up for a great C++ puzzle/question.